# Core-Lightning Derviation Path

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, core-lightning

What derivation path does Core-Lightning use to end up at the Node Public Key (and private key), given a mnemonic seed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The node public key is not derived using BIP32. It's derived from the `hsm_secret` using an HKDF. The `hsmtool` utility can help you derive keys from your `hsm_secret`.

I described in [this issue](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/issues/3687) how every key managed by Core-Lightning is derived. It was a while ago but i don't think it's changed since.